# How Are Transactions kept safe

Tags: database, security, database-design, transactions

I'm curious to know if anyone has experience with this sort of thing. Say I go to a site like Zynga Poker and I buy 5,000,000 chips. 1 minute later, that database for some reason gets corrupted, and the last database backup was 6 hours ago. How might they be asserting that I will not lose the chips I just bought? What are some ways to implement this sort of safety for micro-transactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a high-level view that tries to explain what happens in a lot of databases.

In general, storing information to a database involves two operations:

1. Logging the transaction to secure storage (disk)
2. Modifying the data on data pages

Any data modification is committed only after both these operations take place.  The log may be locally replicated to ensure a safe copy.  It might be stored on SSD for speed.

Normally, users of the database do not worry about the log (although DBAs are *very* concerned).  The database can then be restored by going to the last backup and/or checkpoint and "re-running" the log.

This solves the problem of a database going down locally.  But, it has two other issues.  One is performance on recovery and the other is fatal loss of the database server.  Both of these can be fixed by using database replication, where full copies of the database are stored in physically separate places.

A simple model for this is that you have  databases, with a single point of entry where all queries go through.  This point-of-entry can send any read-only query to any database, but sends data modification queries to all the databases.  It doesn't return until all or most of the underlying databases have committed the transaction.  If a database goes down, then it is simply turned off and queries go to the other databases.  On recovery, it reads recovery files from one of the working databases.

This is a useful model to think about, but it still has a single point of failure.  So, there are more encompassing schemes and peer-to-peer models for managing replication.

Do remember one thing.  **Backing up the data** is never the issue.  The issue is **recovering the data and full functionality**.  Backing things up is just an overhead that we suffer through so in the event that something happens, we can restore functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, In situations like this the company gives people full-refunds if you have proof of purchase, e.g. paypal transaction id.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a high-availability solution for the respective database. SQL Server synchronous mirroring (or synchronous Availability Groups) are zero data loss. (Of course, the [Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem) still applies - there is no true zero data loss).

This works by copying all transactions immediately to a slave server. The commit is only acknowledged if both servers have hardened the transaction to disk.

6 hours of data loss are unacceptable for most businesses.

I don't see what makes this question specific to micro-transactions. Any kind of important data can and should be protected in a way that bounds the maximal amount of data loss and the maximal amount of downtime.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title